# how to filter tree view with dynamic field odoo-10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

i added 'location_id' field to res.user to connect user to a certain location

class ResUser(models.Model):
    _inherit='res.users'

```
current_location_id=fields.Many2one('physical.location',string="Current Loction")
allowed_location_ids=fields.Many2many('physical.location',string="Allowed Location")
```

i wanted to filter only the visits with current_location_id = user_current_location_id

```
<filter string="My visits" name="filter_my_visits"
                        domain="[('current_location_id','=',current_location_id)]"/>
```

**which gives this error message**

```
    Uncaught Error: Failed to evaluate search criterions: 
{"code":400,"message":"Evaluation Error","data":{"type":"local_exception","debug":"Local evaluation failure\nNameError: name 'current_location_id' is not defined\n\n{\"domains\":[[],\"[('current_location_id','=',current_location_id)]\"],\"contexts\":[{\"lang\":\"en_US\",\"tz\":false,\"uid\":1,\"params\":{\"action\":354,\"min\":1,\"limit\":80,\"view_type\":\"list\",\"model\":\"visit.visit\",\"menu_id\":241,\"_push_me\":false}},{}],\"group_by_seq\":[]}"}}
```

the only fields available in view to be called directly are uid lang ... etc
**so i tried to override read method to update context, but it doesn't seem to be updated in the view,still gives undefined 'current_location_id'**

```
    @api.multi
    def read(self, fields=None, load='_classic_read'):
        ctx = self.env.context.copy() 
        ctx.update({ 'user_current_location_id':self.env.user.current_location_id.id})

        return super(Visit,self.with_context(ctx)).read(fields=fields,load=load)
```

visit_tree_view

```
 <record id="visit_visit_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">visit.visit.tree</field>
    <field name="model">visit.visit</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Visits">
            <field name="name" />
            <field name="date"/>
            <field name="visit_type" />
            <field name="patient_id"/>
            <field name="hcp_id"/>
            <field name="current_location_id" />
            <field name="user_current_location_id"/>
            <field name="severity"/>
            <field name="state"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

visit action

```
<record id="visit_visit_act" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Visit</field>
    <field name="res_model">visit.visit</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="context">{'search_default_filter_my_visits':1}</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_visit_filter"/>
</record>
```

here is what i did :

```
 @api.multi
def vsit_action(self):
    ctx = self.env.context.copy()

    ctx.update({'search_default_current_location_id': self.env.user.current_location_id.id,
                'user_current_location_id': self.env.user.current_location_id.id})
    return {
        'name': 'Visit',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'visit.visit',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'context': dict(ctx),
        'search_view_id': self.env.ref('eroyal_visit.view_visit_filter').id
    }
```

the filter:

```
    <filter string="My visits" name="filter_my_visits"
                            domain="[('current_location_id', '=', context.get('user_current_location_id'))]"/>


the visit action
     <record id="visit_visit_act" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Visit</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_visit_visit"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
         <field name="code">
                action = env['visit.visit'].vsit_action()


         </field>
    </record>
```

**the default_search_current_id is working fine ,but the filter filter_my_visits does filter the view with current_location_id=none while its correctly set in context
tanks**

Comment: I don't understand your filter. What do you want to achieve? If you want to filter by a given location, just put the field into the search view. An example: in customers tree you can search for a tag, but instead of typing in the searchterm and pressing enter (fast search), you will have to type the searchterm, choose the "field" to search for (in my example tags; either with mouse or arrow keys) and then press enter.

Comment: i updated the question , the problem that i want to set a default filter and i dont want to give it static value neither want the user to type the value ,i want to set its value to the user_current_location_id,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible with a little workaround. Instead of using a `ir.actions.act_window` try to use a `ir.actions.server` which should return a window action.
Why? Because you need a possibility to get the user's location ID into the context of that window action. I only see this possibility by using a server action with code.

Just fill up the context for the window action with the location ID:

```py
ctx = dict(env.context,
    {'user_location_id': env.user.current_location_id.id,
     'search_default_filter_my_visits': 1}
return {
    'name': 'Visit',
    'view_type': 'form',
    'res_model': 'visit.visit',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'context': ctx,
    'search_view_id': env.ref('my_module.view_visit_filter');
}
```

And for your filter:

```xml
<filter string="My visits" name="filter_my_visits"
    domain="[('current_location_id', '=', context.get('user_location_id')]"/>
```

Comment: Little hint: try to search the xml code of Odoo by `ir.actions.server` ;-) -> [example](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/crm/views/crm_lead_views.xml#L673)

Comment: thank you very much CZoellner ..i edited the question to conclude what i have managed to do