# Domain filter based on field in res.users for Odoo XML tree view

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

My question is:

**How can I reference a field in res.user and use it as a custom filter when opening a tree view in Odoo 10?**

I extended res.user to add a field called: `assigned_office`. This is a Selection field.

I am now trying to use this value to filtering records when calling a specific window action to filter records by default.

I have tried adding the following to my Window Action, but it gave me an error 
`(NameError: name 'user' not defined)`.

```
<field name="domain">[('responsible_office','=',user.assigned_office)]</field>
```

I have tried to modify the search view by adding variations of this to the existing filter:

```
('responsible_office','=',user.assigned_office)
('responsible_office','=',ref='self.assigned_office))
('responsible_office','=',ref=assigned_office)
```

But I am also getting errors:

> Error: Failed to evaluate search criterions: 
>   {"code":400,"message":"Evaluation
>   Error","data":{"type":"local_exception","debug":"Local evaluation
>   failure\nExpected \")\", got \"(name)\"\n\n{\"domains\":[[],\"[
>   ('expiration_date','<=',(context_today())
>   ,('responsible_org','=',ref='self['assigned_org']')
>   ]\"],\"contexts\":[{\"lang\":\"en_US\",\"tz\":false,\"uid\":1,\"search_default_weekly_expirees_filter\":1,\"params\":{\"action\":205}},{}],\"group_by_seq\":[]}"}}

I am obviously doing something wrong and I hope there is a simple answer.

**Here is my code:**

**Window Action:**

```
<record id="my_tool_weekly_expirees_action" model="ir.actions.act_window" >              
  <field name="name">Weekly Expirees</field>
  <field name="res_model">my_tool.member</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
  <field name="context">{"search_default_weekly_expirees_filter":1}</field>  
  <field name="view_id" ref="weekly_expirees_view"/>         
</record>
```

**SEARCH:**

```
<record id="members_search_view" model="ir.ui.view" >
  <field name="name">Search</field>
  <field name="model">my_tool.member</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <search>
          <field name="first_name"/> 
          <field name="last_name"/>

          <field name="expiration_date" string="weekly_expirees" filter_domain="[('expiration_date','&lt;=',(context_today())]"/>  
          <separator/>
          <filter string="Weekly Expirees" name="weekly_expirees_filter" domain="[('expiration_date','&lt;=',(context_today())]" help="..."/>
          <separator/>             

          <field name="expiration_date"/>
          <field name="responsible_office"/>
      </search>
  </field>      
</record>
```

**TREE VIEW**

```
<record id="members_list_view" model="ir.ui.view" >
  <field name="name">members.list</field>
  <field name="model">my_tool.member</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">       
      <tree>          
      <field name="first_name"/>
      <field name="middle_name"/>
      <field name="last_name"/>             
      <field name="expiration_date"/> 
      <field name="responsible_office"/> 
      <field name="country"/>  
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

I have searched stackoverflow.com and the forums at odoo.com and found complicated approaches that I either do not understand or want to do:

The most promising is, but it still seems to be a hack work around:

[Odoo v9 domain filter with value user.id throws error that user is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052586/odoo-v9-domain-filter-with-value-user-id-throws-error-that-user-is-not-defined)

Another one that I found that might be even better is.

[how to filter tree view with dynamic field odoo-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056031/how-to-filter-tree-view-with-dynamic-field-odoo-10)

Answer (score 2):

The most 2 simple ways to get your domain working will be:

- Create a Security `ir.rule` record for the model where you will be able to use the variable `user` to refer to the current user in the domain_force field, like:

  ```
  <record id="my_tool_member_rule" model="ir.rule">
      <field name="name">My Tool Members Rule</field>
      <field name="model_id" ref="my_tool.member"/>
      <field name="domain_force">[('responsible_office','=',user.assigned_office)]</field>
      <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
      <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
      <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
      <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
  </record>
  ```
- Override the model `my_tool.member` search method to add the custom domain, like:

`from odoo import api, models
class MyToolMember(models.Model):
    _name = 'my_tool.member'`

```
    def search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, count=False):
        args.append(('responsible_office', '=', self.env.user.assigned_office))
        return super(MyToolMember, self).search(args, offset=0, limit=None, order=order, count=False)
```